# Set default 'value' of custom Component v-model for v-text-field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Basically, I am using a custom component someone else wrote, and I want to set a default value for this `v-text-field` and i have tried EVERYTHING to override the editedItem.color v-model.
Nothing I am capable of coming up with will work!

I am a laravel php dev, and I could really use some help from my stack friends here.
I am at a new job, and i do not wish to fail.

```
<div v-if="formState === 'create'">
  <v-text-field
    v-model="editedItem.color"
    :default="'#FF0000'"
    :value="'#FF0000'"
    :disabled="true"
    label="Color*"
   />
</div>
```

As far as data, when i go the custom component, the data is as follows:

```
  data: () => ({
    formState: 'create',
    loading: false,
    items: [],
    editedItem: {},
    selectedItems: [],
  }),
```

This seems like something that should be really easy. Just set a default value, and send that to the API. But with the v-model, it will not accept a v-bind:value or v-bind:default

This is a Vuetify component, and I am a newb Vue dev.

So in Summary, nothing will work without the v-model="editedItem.color", and yet, nothing will work if i do not set that default value.

The issue being that color picker returns an array, and we need it NOT to return an array.

So either I need to set the default value for 'create' mode to the #FF0000 hex value, or i need to parse out the returned value from the v-color-picker and JUST use the hex value and not return the array. So basically it all boils down to intercepting the editedItem.color for either solution.

This is my complete page/tags/index.vue page implementing the custom component.

Thanks SOF Fam!

```
<template>
  <work-custom-table
    v-model="headers"
    :routes="routes"
    :title="title"
    settings-key="crud.table"
    sort-by="name"
    allow-merge
  >
    <template #item.preview="{ item }">
      <v-chip :color="item.color">{{ item.name }}</v-chip>
    </template>
    <template #form="{editedItem, formState}">
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="editedItem.name"
            :disabled="formState === 'view'"
            :rules="[$rules.required]"
            label="Name*"
            hint="*Required"
          />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>

      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="editedItem.description"
            :disabled="formState === 'view'"
            :rules="[$rules.required]"
            label="Description"
          />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>

      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <div v-if="formState === 'create'">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="editedItem.color"
              :disabled="true"
              label="Color*"
            />
          </div>
          <div v-else>
            <v-color-picker
              id="tag-color"
              v-model="editedItem.color"
              :default="'#FF0000'"
              :disabled="formState === 'view'"
              class="elevation-0"
              label="Color*"
              hint="*Required"
              mode="hexa"
              hide-canvas
            />
          </div>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </template>
  </work-custom-table>
</template>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: please share the `editedItem` object, i think you should set that default value like `editedItem:{ color:"#000" ...}`

Comment: That’s what I was thinking. But I tried that I think. I’m riding home from work now, but when I get home I’ll dig for it.

Comment: This just doesn't make any sense to me at all. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

`<v-text-field>` is just a wrapper around an html `<input>`.

And in Vue, on `<input>`s, `v-model` and `value` are mutually exclusive. `value` is only read when you don't have two-way data binding (using `v-model`).

Which means all you need to do is provide the default value in the `editedItem` itself, before passing it to the `<v-text-input>` (and remove `default` & `value`). Example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    formState: 'create',
    editedItem: {
      color: '#FF0000'
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-if="formState === 'create'">
    <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.color" :disabled="true" label="Color*" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, if `editedItem` is coming from another component or from an external API, you'll have to intercept it and populate the default value of `color` on it if `color` does not have a truthy value. A generic example:

```
methods: {
  getEditedItemFromApi() {
    this.$http.get('some/api/url')
      .then(r => this.editedItem = ({ 
        ...r.data,
        // assumming the API returns the editingItem object
        color: r.data.color || '#FF0000'
      }));
 }
}
```

(we're destructuring the response data and adding `color` property to all its existing properties, with a value of its own `color` property if it's anything truthy or the default value if it's falsey.

The gist of it is: you have to populate the default value on the actual property bound to `v-model`, prior to passing it to the `<input>`.

---

Here's the relevant part of Vue documentation on [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components).

---

And, to cover all cases, here's how you'd use a `computed` with `set` and `get`, allowing you map default values:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { id: 'one', color: 'black' },
      { id: 'two' }
    ],
    selectedItem: null
  }),
  computed: {
    editingItem: {
      get() {
        return { ...this.selectedItem, color: this.selectedItem?.color || '#FF0000' };
      },
      set(item) {
        this.selectedItem = item;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.flexer { 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.flexer span {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedItem">
    <option :value="null">Select item</option>
    <option v-for="item in items" :value="item">{{item.id}}</option>
  </select>
  <div class="flexer" v-if="selectedItem">
    <input v-model="editingItem.color" :disabled="true" />
    <span :style="{ borderColor: editingItem.color }" /> 
   </div>
   <pre v-html="{ selectedItem, editingItem }" />
</div>
```

This would also cover the case when it's coming as `prop`, from a parent.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! 
It's coming from a custom component! 

I do not want to set the that value every single time as '#FF0000', but just in this one case. My proposed question is rather hacky unto itself. But if I can figure out how to override the v-model, or bind data to it, then i can solve my other problem as well.

Comment: In that case use a `computed` for that case, with `set` and `get`. I appended an example. So you're actually editing one property through a computed property which modifies the value before it's passed on / retrieved.

Comment: Thank you! You are a Vuetiful person! You’re saving my butt. For realz!

Comment: I tried to refine the example and added a `<pre>` hopefully making it more clear. `editingItem` is just an interface for modifying `selectedItem` which adds default `color` on the fly. Think of `selectedItem` as a protected prop and `editingItem` are it's setter and getter (in fact, that's exactly what they are).

Comment: This color is a hex value that's being shipped off to the laravel API. 
All the other values are totally fine the way they are. 

So the answer lies in the getters and setters is what you're saying. I briefly started making one earlier. 
If i wanted to get and set for just .color
Would i nest it like so: 
editedItem:{color{ get(), set{}}}, I know that's kinda awful in a comment.

Comment: Here's the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter). Getter needs to return the object and setter has to take it as param. If you're using Typescript, their types must match. They're both functions.

Comment: If you need to set color to empty string: `color:""` you will need to substitute `||` with the nullish coalescing operator `??` in the getter: 
`color: this.selectedItem?.color ?? '#FF0000'`

Answer (score 0):

My solution has little to do with VUE, but hopefully it can help someone, I hit that a personal state where you start looking for other solutions.

The problem is that on 'create' the color-picker was returning an array, where on edit, it was returning the hex value, so my (maybe a little hacky) solution was to set a default value for the color value initially, and then set color on edit.
But instead of manipulating vue vars with getters and setters,
I went into my Laravel API FormRequest instance, and you can prepare your data before validation using `prepareForValidation()` method.

I did this:

```
protected function prepareForValidation(){
    if(gettype($this->color) == 'array'){
        $this->merge(['color' => $this->color['hex']]);
    }
}
```

I was able to check for an array, and if array, parse out the value. Sadly, I was not able to get the get and set to work for me.

Thanks!